# Haskell program that applies a function to a list [0..n] and sums the elements of the list

Tags: haskell

I want to create the function allSum which should be declared in this way

```
 allSum::    (Int->Int)->(Int->Int)
```

this is what it should do:

```
(allSum f) n = f (0 )+ f (1)+ f (2) +…+ f (n)
```

this is my attempt:

```
 sum1   = foldr (+)0

 allSum:: (int->int) -> (int->int)
 allSum f  = \n -> ( sum1 [ f(x)| x <-[0..n]])
```

however, it doesn't work and I am not sure why.

Comment: The type is `Int`, with a capital `I`.  Not `int`.  Also, always remember to post the error or something more informative than "it doesn't work".

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Do you get an error?  Does it compile but not give you the correct result?

Comment: Thanks. it was just the int instead of the Int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `int` to `Int` it will work just fine:

```
sum1 = foldr (+) 0

allSum :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
allSum f = \n -> sum1 [ f(x) | x <- [0..n] ]
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3d49f213df9b43c)

---

On a side note you can write your `allSum` function as:

```
allSum :: (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int)
allSum f = \n -> sum . fmap f $ [0..n]
```

Comment: The pointfree variant `allSum f = sum . map f . enumFromTo 0` also looks nice.